# error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a simple script to watch change in file,
**index.js**

```
var watch = require('node-watch');

watch('C:\CRM\log.txt', function(filename) {
  console.log(filename, ' changed.');
});
```

I am trying to run it via command

```
forever start index.js
```

Its showing output:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: index.js
```

and the control is returning to command prompt, instead of staying there! How can I keep it running and get the console.log output as soon as file is changed?

Comment: Why don't you use the watch functionality of forever (-w) ?

Answer (score 2):

`forever start index.js` will start up in the background. From the sounds of it, you want it to stay in the foreground. Use `forever index.js` instead.